# Why django don't need all fields to test a model

Tags: django, unit-testing, model

I have a model like this:

```
class CreateDeal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    fuel = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    mileage = models.PositiveIntegerField(db_index=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=17) 
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True)
    car_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='car_picture')
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(db_index=True)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

and I have a test class to test the model above like this:

```
class CreateDealTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.user = User.objects.create_user(
            username='alfa', email='alfa@hotmail.com', password='top_secret'
        )
        self.deal = CreateDeal.objects.create(
            name='deal1', mileage=100, price=25, user=self.user
        )

    def test_deal_name(self):
        deal = CreateDeal.objects.get(name='deal1')
        expected_deal_name = f'{self.deal.name}'
        self.assertAlmostEqual(expected_deal_name, str(deal))
```

if I run the test I have:

```
Ran 1 test in 0.166s

OK
```

My question is why django don't raise an exception since almost all fields in my model are required. And what I don't understand is if I remove one field of `Createdeal` in my `setUp` (like mileage, price, user or name) I have an error.

For instance if I remove `mileage`, I have this error:

> raise utils.IntegrityError(*tuple(e.args))
>
> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1048, "Column 'mileage' cannot be null")

Comment: What do you mean by almost all fields are required? What model are you talking about?

Comment: In the model `CreateDeal` the fields `available` `created_on` are not required but all others are required, I am wrong ?

Comment: You are correct. Can you try creating `CreateDeal` record in admin without thous fields? Interesting if you'll be able to do this. In general - it's possible that you changed schema but didn't run migrations/save method is overrided and some default values are set there/there is pre_save signal setting some default values.

Comment: I think @iklinac has provided the answer, thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Charfield, Imagefield and Textfield can be empty string which is valid at the database level, some of your fields have default values so they will be written if not set so that makes them also valid at the database level.

PositiveIntegerField and Foreign key cannot be set to empty string, just to value or null so they will fail since `null=False` by default.

The default `blank=False` option is only applied at the validation level, not at the database level. This means if you call `full_clean()` on your model, it will raise a `ValidationError`. But nothing stops you from saving an invalid model (`save()` does not call `full_clean()` as explained [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.full_clean)).

Comment: Ah ok, now it's clearer but when you talk about username field
 are you referring to my `name` field ? because I don't see where this `username_validator` is written

Comment: @YacineRouizi I am refering to username field of User model, that is Django internal User model, visible in Django source code -> https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L315

Comment: ah ok I see but what about my `name` field, why it's required ? is this because I have the method `__str__` (`def __str__(self):
        return self.name`)

Comment: you are using self.deal.name in your test, it should not throw integrity error but test will still fail

Comment: ah ok I hadn't noticed that thank you very much, now everything is clear

Comment: Note that if you call `clean()` on your model, it will raise a `ValidationError` if one of your `CharField`s is empty. That happens if you create a `ModelForm` and then check `is_valid()` on the form. The form will not be valid if you leave `description` empty for example.

Comment: The answer above is not really correct. Validators aren't applied at the database level, so nothing stops you from saving an empty `username` on a `User` model into the database. Validation errors are only raised when you `clean()` a model (and `clean()` isn't called when you `save()` a model). What's applied at the database level are **constraints**: Not `null` constraints for numbers and foreign keys, or uniqueness constraints.

Comment: @dirkgroten is right, most of validators are not applied on database level